# CTest can not find executable file

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a question about starting the ctest. As I can understand that **ctest** uses CTestTestfile.cmake for the beginning of the unit test. What is the executable file? Why does **ctest** find it as *.exe if it is a CTestTestfile.cmake? What is wrong in my actions?

I have a folder Prj:

[image: Prj folder picture]

and folder `/build` with cmake output (CTestTestfile.cmake is here) as well as all **ctest,cmake**, etc. programs with their dll (is it right?).

Here is the text of CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyTest C)
enable_testing()
include(CTest)

set(SOURCE_EXE simple_test.c)
include_directories(include)

### The most simple test
add_executable(simple_test ${SOURCE_EXE})
add_subdirectory(src)
target_link_libraries(simple_test "./src")

add_test(NAME simple_test COMMAND simple_test)
```

I have received the result in Windows cmd:

[image: cmd screen after ctest cmd]

Comment: Looks like you forgot to **build** the project before testing it. This would explain that ctest cannot find your executable. Also, `target_link_libraries(simple_test "./src")` seems weird: linking is performed with library **file**, but according to `add_subdirectory(src)`, `./src` is **directory**, not a *file*.

Comment: Hm..so strange. I have built project with cmake-GUI and used mingw64 compiler (64-bit Windows). Ok. After "build" should I get this executable file *.exe? Thanks!

Comment: cmake-GUI doesn't **build** the project, it just **configures** it. *Building* is performed by other system, like Make.

Comment: sorry, I can't understand, could you explain what is the sequence of this process? I should have done the procedures one by one as: configuring project with cmake-GUI (there is making of the project) --->built with Make (use Makefile in build/ directory)-----> execute tests with CTest (use *.exe file after build) in the cmd window and that's all. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, exactly this sequence.

Comment: Ok.Thanks! unfortunately, I am looking for a solution for the "build" from Makefile (I have already got a Makefile in built/ directory). A lot information for theLinux platform but for Windows I can't find a simple realization. What are the ways for that are existing?

Comment: Which [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) do you provide for CMake? It should be reflected at the bottom of cmake-GUI window. For build the project you should use a build tool corresponded to the generator.

Comment: I used "MinGW makefiles" and than I choose "Specify native compiler" as "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe". After the "configure" procedure I receive an error - CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles". After that I choose a make program from installed folder MinGW/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe. Further I repeat the "Configure" and receive "Configuring done". I press the "Generate" button and receive "Generating done".

Comment: I receive a lot of files in build/ folder. There is "CTestTestfile.cmake" too. After this procedure I tried to build this file with Window nmake.exe utility, but I haven't got I successfull result (I can show this one). Is it right way or not? Please, if it is possible could you explain to me what are the next manipulations I should do for the "build" program and run the test.

Comment: As you have `mingw32-make.exe` specified as make program, use it for build the project. For build with `nmake.exe` you need to specify [NMake Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/generator/NMake%20Makefiles.html) generator.

Comment: I have done it! I tried to do the next: after getting the Makefile (with cmake-gui.exe) I copied the mingw32-make.exe into the build/ folder and from the Window cmd wrote a command "mingw32-make.exe". After that I received an expecting simple_test.exe in the same folder built/. Further,  I had executed Windows cmd command "simple_test.exe" and received the results of the unit tests. That's all!

Comment: A lot of thanks for Tsyvarev, who helped me to find the way of desicion. Hats off for your work!